# Count if using multiple tabs and specific writing

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, count, countif

I am trying to add all the number of times a name appears in multiple spreadsheets. I seem to be having issues using the formulas I am using. =COUNTIF ('Sheet 6':'Sheet 8'!G1:G124, "Name") is one of the formulas I've tried that does not work. =COUNTIF (Sheet6:Sheet8!G1:G124, "Name") This formula is also giving me problems. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or how to fix it. I am not sure if this is a google sheets problem or what.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=COUNTIF({Sheet6!G1:G124; Sheet8!G1:G124}; "Name")
```